# Ajax Message not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mailchimp

I try to display an error message but it does'nt work.

When the email does'nt exist,
I have this message : Thank you : your email is added

But if the email is always in mailchimp or other error, I haven't message under the button submit.

Do you have an idea to resolve this point ?

Thank you

The detail of the error come from server.

```
string(88) "400: ****** is already a list member. Use PUT to insert or update list members."
array(5) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(77) "http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/"
  ["title"]=>
  string(13) "Member Exists"
  ["status"]=>
  int(400)
  ["detail"]=>
  string(83) "********* is already a list member. Use PUT to insert or update list members."
  ["instance"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

my javascript is

```
          $footer .= '
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#signup').submit(function() {
    $("#message").html("<div class=\"alert alert-info\" style=\"padding:05px; margin-top:5px;\" role=\"alert\">Thank you : your email is added</div>");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ext/api/mailchimp_v3/subscribe.php', // proper url to your "store-address.php" file
      type: 'POST', // <- IMPORTANT
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $('#signup').serialize() + '&ajax=true',
      success: function(msg) {
        var message = '';
        var result = '';
        message = $.parseJSON(msg);
        if (message.status === 'pending') { // success
          result = '<div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">Thank you: an email has sent you for confirmation</div>';
        } else { // error
          result = '<div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">Error ' + message.detail + '</div>';
        }
      },
      complete: function(message) {
        $('#message').html('<div> ' + message.title + '</div>'); // display the message
      }
    });
    $('#fname').attr('value',''); // reset input field
    $('#lname').attr('value',''); // reset input field
    $('#email').attr('value',''); // reset input field
    return false;
  });
});
    </script>';
```

PHP code

```
      if ( isset($_POST['anonymous'])) {
        $list_id = MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_MAILCHIMP_LIST_ANONYMOUS;
        $merge_vars = [
          'FNAME' => '',
          'LNAME' => ''
        ];

      } else {
        $list_id = MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_MAILCHIMP_LIST_CUSTOMERS;

        $merge_vars = [
          'FNAME' => $_POST['firstname'],
          'LNAME' => $_POST['lastname']
        ];
      }

      $array = [
                  'email_address' => $_POST['email'],
                  'merge_fields'  => $merge_vars,
                  'status'        => MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_MAILCHIMP_STATUS_CHOICE
                ];


      if (MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_MAILCHIMP_STATUS_CHOICE == 'pending') {
        $status = 'pending';
      } else {
        $status = 'subscribed';
      }

      $mc = new \MailChimp($key);

    // add the email to your list
       $result = $mc->post('/lists/' . $list_id . '/members', $array);
//send
        json_encode($result);

// If being called via ajax, run the function, else fail - console
      if ( MODULES_HEADER_TAGS_MAILCHIMP_DEBUG == 'True') {

        if ($_POST['ajax']) {
          var_dump($result); // send the response back
        } else {
          var_dump('Method not allowed - please ensure JavaScript is enabled in this browser');
        }
      }
```

Comment: i cant see logical error in your backend... have you tried a `console.log(message)` in your 'else' block (where you assigning a result in case of error) to ensure that your message contains expected data?

Comment: and try to add `error` handler to your ajax call, to be sure that answer is recieved and there are no parse errors. It is always good practice to handle server or parse errors with error handler, it at least saves your time from being wasted by searching bugs in place where there are no bugs :)

Comment: Sorry I am beginner. The only message in my console is above (error 400) when I try to insert some time the same email to create an error.

Comment: ok, that is my advide: 1. add error handler (just call `console.log('ajax error') ` inside to see if there is server/parse error); 2. add `console.log('ajax success/email error')` to where you assigning result in your 'else' block; What you will see will give imformation for the next step

Comment: To help you I inserted the code in php

Comment: Inside the script I inserted your element console, but I have always the same message (see above on the result (string(88) "400:) but no message about the error 400 appear belon the submit button via Error\' + message.detail

Comment: @AlexandrX : I changed a little bit the code now I have a message under the button called undefined (success and error not appear) . Also I inserted the php code. Inside the console, for error server, always the same synthax. see : complete: function(message)